# saving figures in pyplot produces blank windows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python and matplotlib.pyplot to produce various plots.

I am not making the plots show(), I am instead saving them using matplotlib.pyplot.savefig() and matplotlib.pyplot.clf()

As the code runs, X11 brings up a cascade of blank windows - 1 for every plot that I save - until the code has finished.

The code works and my plots are saved as desired, but the blank windows which appear while the code is running are annoying.

How can I stop this please?

---

Edit:

This happens on all of my code. I guess the only relevant code is what I already put:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig('{0}.png' .format(index))
matplotlib.pyplot.clf()
```

---

Okay, after further invetigation, my problem only occurs if I have imported Gpy. Here is a simple example that shows my issue:

```
import numpy as np
import GPy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,10,1)

for i in range(10):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x)
    plt.savefig('test_{0}.png' .format(i))
   plt.clf()
```

Of course now, I can just remove the
    import Gpy
line if I don't need it.

My version of python is 2.7.3

Comment: It's not clear to me, why you are calling `plt.clf` at the end. Isn't `plt.close` what you actually want to do?

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using? Could you *increase* the size of your code example to show a minimal, complete and verifiable example that produces the undesired behavior on your side, but such that we can also run it, to verify?

Comment: Also consider using the OO interface and a non-interactive backend (ex Agg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty good chance that GPy is somehow turning on matplotlibs interactive mode.  You can turn it off again using

plt.ioff()

Hopefully that works